# How to detect if UILocalnotification sound is playing or not

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

In my application I am using 'UILocalNotification` with a 30 sec audio file. I fire the notification when device is in lock mode. I tried to drag the notification on lock screen, then application will open at that Notification sound is playing, I need to recognize notification sound is playing or not  when app is in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

No good way, but you can use NSTimer. Start timer after show notification and make work when timer notify you. It will work, but use it only if any other resolution don't work.